# Show bound on $\ln^2 (x-y)$ for $x-y \geq 1$.

Tags: calculus, analysis, inequality

In 'The bound state of weakly coupled Schrödinger operators in one and two dimensions' from Barry Simon, he uses for any $\delta >0$, there exists a constant $C_\delta$ such that

$$|\ln (x-y)|^2 \leqslant C_\delta \left(1+x^\delta\right)\left(1+y^\delta\right) ; \quad(x-y) \geqslant 1.$$

I believe this inequality is true, but I'm struggling to prove this. I've considered using:
$$\ln(1+x) \leq c_\delta x^\delta$$
Then applying this to
$$\ln(1 + (x - y -1)) \leq c_\delta(x-y)^\delta$$
but I am unsure what to do from here. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Hope someone will check this, but I'd go with something like this:

\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
|\ln(x-y)|^2 &\leq C_{\delta}(1 + x^{\delta} + y^{\delta} + (xy)^{\delta}) \\\\
& \leq C_{\delta}(1 + (x+y)^{2\delta}) 
\\\\
& \leq C_{\delta}(1 + x + y)^{2\delta}
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

Whence

$$\ln(x-y) \leq \sqrt{C_{\delta}}|1+x+y|^{\delta}$$

With a suitable constant $C_{\delta}$

I'm opened to critics, so before downvoting tell me at least what's wrong.